# Merge two or more elements of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, merge, tostring

Is there any possibility to merge two elements of `ArrayList`?

This is my array = `[u,s,m,a,t,t]`
and I want to have something like this = `[us,matt]`

I've tried to use toString(), and replace('',''), but it merges whole array `[usmatt]`.
Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean but what you try to achieve could be done this way:

Pseudo-code:

```
String[] array1 = [u,s,m,a,t,t]
String a = array[0]+array[1]
String b = array[2]+array[3]+array[4]+array[5]
String[] array2 = [a,b]
```

Comment: yeah, but it's not the only one example, sometimes the array is longer

Comment: So you want to do it dynamically? Is there a factor determining what the length of each word must be?

Comment: yeah, but it's hard to say, because it's small part of bigger application, but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just try to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (For any length ArrayList.)

```
public static void MergeArrayList() {
    ArrayList<Character> Array = new ArrayList<Character>() {{ add('u');add('s');
                                    add('m');add('a');add('t');add('t');}};
    ArrayList<String> newArray = new ArrayList<>();
    int n=2; // Change this to indicate where you need to make the cut.
    String str="";        
    for (int i=0;i<Array.size();i++) {
        if (i==n) {
            newArray.add(str);
            str="";
        }
        str += Array.get(i);
    }
    newArray.add(str);
    System.out.println(Array);
    System.out.println(newArray);        
}
```